# When I install python library "curl_cffi" on centos8, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1GcR.png)

python version:Python 3.6.8

I try to use command

```
pip3 install curl_cffi
```

and

```
pip install curl_cffi
```

,but the same error occurred
I tried to search, but couldn't find the answer
What should I do to successfully install this curl_cffi
please help me

Comment: Please include in the question *as text*: which error occurred?

Comment: 1. you are missing curl headers, installing curl-dev might help.  2. you are building for python3.6 - which has been unsupported for >2 years now - when first release of curl_cffi was out, python 3.6 was already EOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your python version:

`curl_cffi` requires **at least python 3.7** or above and **your python is 3.6.8**

Please install a newer version of **python >=3.7**

https://pypi.org/project/curl-cffi/

[image]